# Coldfusion LDAP from Docker Image

Tags: coldfusion, ldap, coldfusion-2021

I am trying to establish a LDAP connection (`<cfldap>`) from within a Docker image of Coldfusion 2021. It would be hard to post any relavent code here simply because it would expose our AD tree, however, the same code I am trying to run works just fine from an installed copy of CF2021 on a linux server.

The reason for using a Docker image (vs. install) in this instance, is an attempt to setup a local development (MACOS) environment. So far, everything seems to be working great with the exception of LDAP calls.

Note: I have successfully run a `ldapsearch` call from a bash shell within the container.

The error I'm getting:

> An error has occurred while trying to execute query :Could not resolve
> a valid ldap host

The Docker image repo I pulled from:
https://hub.docker.com/r/adobecoldfusion/coldfusion

- Update: I've just noticed CF version differences between the server that isn't having the problems:
  Linux Version: 2021,0,01,325996 (installed a few weeks ago non-Docker)
  Local MACOS: 2021,0,02,328618 (Docker)
- Update 2: We've installed a fresh ColdFusion 2021 Docker image on a Linux box directly connected to our network and we are still seeing this issue. This narrows the issue down to Adobe Cold Fusion 2021's interaction with Docker and it's ability to do `<CFLDAP>`.
- Update 3: 10-13-2021 - It would appear the CF team is aware of this, has confirmed the bug and is looking into it.
- Update 4: 11-12-2021 - This bug is related to the version of Java running within the Docker image. "Adobe CF support suggested updating to JAVA SE 11.0.13 (LTS) inside the docker container" which has worked when tested. Expect CF to solve the problem in future Docker CF2021 releases.

Comment: Nice work. You should post the final update as an answer (including the bug number) so it's more visible and folks can vote on it.

Comment: I wasn't the person who posted the bug (I only raised the issue with Adobe Support), so I don't have that information, however.. here is the thread: https://community.adobe.com/t5/coldfusion-discussions/coldfusion-ldap-from-docker-image-not-working/m-p/12408354

Comment: Gotcha. Still worth posting as an answer IMO if it fixes the issue IMO (:.